# insert values in table by condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I need to insert data by condition

```
SELECT id,
CASE
  WHEN (gender = 'Female') THEN update gender set gender = 'Male'
  WHEN (gender = 'Male') THEN update gender set gender = 'Female'
 END AS gender
FROM era;
```

Am I on the right way and is it possible something similar to this synax in sql?

Comment: Are you trying to insert records or edit existing records?

Comment: If you want to *insert* data, why does your query use `select`.  The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to *update*, then use:

```
UPDATE era
SET gender = CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 'Female' ELSE 'Male' END
WHERE gender IN ('Male', 'Female');
```

This would toggle all gender values from male to female and vice-versa.